# Making one of my columns default the DateCreated to current time

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[James] (
    [JamesID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] DATETIME NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.James] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([JamesID] ASC)
);
```

1. How might I make it so new entries have the DateCreated filled out automatically when I create new entries.
2. What about existing data that has not had that column filled out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting from scratch and assuming this is SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[James] (
    [JamesID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.James] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([JamesID] ASC)
);
```

If you want to update the table you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.James
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_namehere DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FOR DateCreated;
```

However, any current `NULL` values will remain `NULL` with the `ALTER TABLE` solution. How you want to address this depends if you want to backfill information.

Comment: Thanks man, although changing the definition from NULL to NOT NULL is unfortunately not working, but this may be because of visual studio correcting me. This is helpful, thanks.

Comment: It's probably because you have NULL values in the table already? I'm not sure how you would want to deal with old entries that don't have date information associated with them...